# Scattered Plot with force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, force-layout

I'm trying to make a scattered plot with force simulation in D3 with two axis X and Y and I would like to apply the force layout, just to avoid overlapping points, but I'm getting the exact opposite effect (the points are overlapping and they are not well positioned)

This is my code so far:

```
// Create SVG and margins

var margin = {top: 52, right: 78, bottom: 52, left: 78}
var myWidth = 900 - margin.left - margin.right
var myHeight = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width', myWidth + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', myHeight + margin.top + margin.bottom)

var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.top + ")")

// Scale

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([2,10])
    .range([myHeight, 0])

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0,100])
    .range([0, myWidth])

// Axis

var yAxisCall = d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(10)
g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y-axis")
  .call(yAxisCall)

var xAxisCall = d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(10)
g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x-axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + myHeight + ")")
  .call(xAxisCall)

 // Helper Functions

var myIbus = function(d,i){
  if (d.ibus) {
    return d.ibus[1] ? (y((d.ibus[0] + d.ibus[1])/2)) : (y(d.ibus[0]))
  }
  else return 0
 }

var myABV = function(d,i){
  if (d.abv) {
    return d.abv[1] ? (x((d.abv[0] + d.abv[1])/2)) : (x(d.abv[0]))
  }
  else return 0
 }


// Force Simulation

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
  .force('collide', d3.forceCollide())
  .on('tick', ticked)


function ticked() {

  var myCircles = g.selectAll('circle')
    .data(nodes)

  myCircles.enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr("cx", myIbus)
    .attr("cy", myABV)
    .attr("r", 8)

  myCircles.exit().remove()

}
```

I have a working example in https://bl.ocks.org/Jesus82/ad5c6fb46f8be5a9d3e763f8a1ba03d7 with the data I'm using (I want to visualize beer styles according to their ABV-alcohol % and IBUS-bitterness), and where the data is in ranges, I just use their mean.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing about using a force simulation to avoid overlapping points in a scatter plot is to use the `d3.forceX` and `d3.forceY` methods to set the positions, and `d3.forceCollide` just to avoid the overlapping.

Therefore, your simulation should be:

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
  .force('collide', d3.forceCollide().radius(8))
  .force('x', d3.forceX(myIbus))
  .force('y', d3.forceY(myABV))
  .on('tick', ticked);
```

And in your `ticked` function:

```
function ticked() {
  myCircles.attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y
    });
};
```

You can play with the `strengths` of those forces: giving more strength to the `forceX/Y` forces makes the scatter more accurate, but with more overlapping points; giving more strength to the `forceCollide` reduces the overlapping, but makes the visualisation less accurate.

Besides that, you have some minor problems:

1. Move the enter, update and exit selection to **outside** the `ticked` function;
2. Maybe I'm wrong, but your `myIbus` and `myABV` methods seem to have the wrong scales (just swap them).
3. Move your data variable initialisation to before the update selection.

Here is your updated code:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var nodes = [{
        name: 'abbey_dubbel',
        abv: [6, 7.6],
        ibus: [15, 25]
      },
      {
        name: 'abbey_tripel',
        abv: [7.5, 9.5],
        ibus: [20, 40]
      },
      {
        name: 'ale',
        abv: [0],
        ibus: [0]
      },
      {
        name: 'amber_ale',
        abv: [0],
        ibus: [0]
      },
      {
        name: 'amber_lager',
        abv: [4.7, 5.5],
        ibus: [18, 30]
      },
      {
        name: 'american_IPA',
        abv: [6, 14],
        ibus: [40, 70]
      },
      {
        name: 'american_pale_ale',
        abv: [4.5, 6.2],
        ibus: [30, 50]
      },
      {
        name: 'american_strong_ale',
        abv: [8, 12],
        ibus: [30, 60]
      },
      {
        name: 'baltic_porter',
        abv: [6.5, 9.5],
        ibus: [20, 40]
      },
      {
        name: 'barley_wine',
        abv: [8, 12],
        ibus: [50, 100]
      },
      {
        name: 'belgian_ale',
        abv: [8, 5.5],
        ibus: [20, 30]
      },
      {
        name: 'belgian_strong_ale',
        abv: [7.5, 10.5],
        ibus: [22, 35]
      },
      {
        name: 'berliner_weisse',
        abv: [2.8, 3.8],
        ibus: [3, 8]
      },
      {
        name: 'biere_de_garde',
        abv: [6, 8.5],
        ibus: [18, 28]
      },
      {
        name: 'black_IPA',
        abv: [5.5, 9],
        ibus: [50, 90]
      },
      {
        name: 'blond_ale',
        abv: [6, 7.5],
        ibus: [15, 30]
      },
      {
        name: 'brown_ale',
        abv: [4.2, 5.4],
        ibus: [20, 30]
      },
      {
        name: 'brut_ipa',
        abv: [5, 7.5],
        ibus: [40, 60]
      },
      {
        name: 'cider',
        abv: [0],
        ibus: [0]
      },
      {
        name: 'doppelbock',
        abv: [7, 10],
        ibus: [16, 26]
      },
      {
        name: 'dunkel',
        abv: [4.5, 5.6],
        ibus: [18, 28]
      },
      {
        name: 'ESB',
        abv: [4.6, 6.2],
        ibus: [30, 50]
      },
      {
        name: 'foreign_extra_stout',
        abv: [6.3, 8],
        ibus: [50, 70]
      },
      {
        name: 'fruit_beer',
        abv: [2, 8],
        ibus: [40]
      },
      {
        name: 'fruity_lambic',
        abv: [5, 7],
        ibus: [10]
      },
      {
        name: 'gose',
        abv: [4.2, 4.8],
        ibus: [5, 12]
      },
      {
        name: 'gueuze_lambic',
        abv: [5, 8],
        ibus: [10]
      },
      {
        name: 'imperial_IPA',
        abv: [7.5, 10],
        ibus: [60, 120]
      },
      {
        name: 'imperial_pils',
        abv: [0],
        ibus: [0]
      },
      {
        name: 'imperial_porter',
        abv: [4.8, 6.5],
        ibus: [25, 50]
      },
      {
        name: 'imperial_stout',
        abv: [5, 7.5],
        ibus: [40, 60]
      },
      {
        name: 'india_style_lager',
        abv: [0],
        ibus: [0]
      },
      {
        name: 'IPA',
        abv: [5, 7.5],
        ibus: [40, 60]
      },
      {
        name: 'lager',
        abv: [0],
        ibus: [0]
      },
      {
        name: 'lambic',
        abv: [5, 6.5],
        ibus: [10]
      },
      {
        name: 'landbier',
        abv: [4.7, 7.4],
        ibus: [16, 22]
      },
      {
        name: 'neipa',
        abv: [6, 9],
        ibus: [25, 60]
      },
      {
        name: 'old_ale',
        abv: [5.5, 9],
        ibus: [30, 60]
      },
      {
        name: 'pale_lager',
        abv: [4.6, 6],
        ibus: [18, 25]
      },
      {
        name: 'pilsener',
        abv: [4.4, 5.2],
        ibus: [22, 40]
      },
      {
        name: 'porter',
        abv: [4, 5.4],
        ibus: [28, 35]
      },
      {
        name: 'premium_lager',
        abv: [4.2, 5.8],
        ibus: [30, 45]
      },
      {
        name: 'quadrupel',
        abv: [8, 12],
        ibus: [20, 35]
      },
      {
        name: 'saison',
        abv: [3.5, 9.5],
        ibus: [20, 35]
      },
      {
        name: 'scotch_ale',
        abv: [6.5, 10],
        ibus: [17, 35]
      },
      {
        name: 'session_IPA',
        abv: [3, 5],
        ibus: [35, 60]
      },
      {
        name: 'smoked',
        abv: [0],
        ibus: [0]
      },
      {
        name: 'sour_red_brown',
        abv: [4.6, 6.5],
        ibus: [10, 25]
      },
      {
        name: 'sour_wild_ale',
        abv: [0],
        ibus: [0]
      },
      {
        name: 'specialty_grain',
        abv: [0],
        ibus: [0]
      },
      {
        name: 'stout',
        abv: [4, 6],
        ibus: [20, 40]
      },
      {
        name: 'sweet_stout',
        abv: [4, 6],
        ibus: [20, 40]
      },
      {
        name: 'weissbier',
        abv: [4.3, 5.6],
        ibus: [8, 15]
      },
      {
        name: 'weizen_bock',
        abv: [6.5, 9],
        ibus: [15, 30]
      },
      {
        name: 'wheat_ale',
        abv: [4, 5.5],
        ibus: [15, 30]
      },
      {
        name: 'witbier',
        abv: [4.5, 5.5],
        ibus: [8, 20]
      }
    ]
    // Create SVG and margins

    var margin = {
      top: 52,
      right: 78,
      bottom: 52,
      left: 78
    }
    var myWidth = 900 - margin.left - margin.right
    var myHeight = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom

    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
      .attr('width', myWidth + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr('height', myHeight + margin.top + margin.bottom)

    var g = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.top + ")")

    // Scale

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([2, 10])
      .range([myHeight, 0])

    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 100])
      .range([0, myWidth])

    // Axis

    var yAxisCall = d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(10)
    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y-axis")
      .call(yAxisCall)

    var xAxisCall = d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(10)
    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x-axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + myHeight + ")")
      .call(xAxisCall)

    // Helper Functions

    var myIbus = function(d, i) {
      if (d.ibus) {
        return d.ibus[1] ? (x((d.ibus[0] + d.ibus[1]) / 2)) : (x(d.ibus[0]))
      } else return 0
    }

    var myABV = function(d, i) {
      if (d.abv) {
        return d.abv[1] ? (y((d.abv[0] + d.abv[1]) / 2)) : (y(d.abv[0]))
      } else return 0
    }


    // Force Simulation

    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
      .force('collide', d3.forceCollide().radius(8))
      .force('x', d3.forceX(myIbus))
      .force('y', d3.forceY(myABV))
      .on('tick', ticked);

    var myCircles = g.selectAll('circle')
      .data(nodes)

    myCircles = myCircles.enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr("r", 8)
      .merge(myCircles);

    myCircles.exit().remove()


    function ticked() {
      myCircles.attr("cx", function(d) {
          return d.x
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
          return d.y
        });
    };
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Awesome, I was totally missing the `d3.forceY` and `d3.forceX part`, and it was not clear how to iterate the function, now thinks gets clear. Thanks a lot!